# How to use Extend Custom Control and use in Window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I want to make a window similar to the Android screen that shows the state of bluetooth, wifi..etc. I have a class that checks the state of said device and returns a byte value of 0 for off, 1 for on and 0xFF for error. I then made a Button (probably should be ToggleButton..but i'm very new to WPF)

```
public class ToggleTaskButton : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase
{
    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public Color MyBackgroundColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(MyBackgroundColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyBackgroundColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyBackgroundColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyBackgroundColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ToggleTaskButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ToggleTaskButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

A note about that class above is that I'm thinking that I don't want a dependency property?? Instead I would rather set a value and the background color changes to the appropriate color. 0 would be gray, 1 would be green >1 would be red. One thing I don't know how to do

I then made a Bluetooth UserControl and then changed the type to ToggleTaskButton. The project this is just a Class Library, so I don't get a resource dictionary :/ I was trying to get the button click portion to work correctly before I posted this. Sorry for the mess.

```
<ata:ToggleTaskButton x:Class="AdvancedTaskAssigner.Controls.BluetoothControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:ata="clr-namespace:AdvancedTaskAssigner.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded" Click="ToggleTaskButton_Click"
                      ImageSource="/AdvancedTaskAssigner;component/Resources/Bluetooth.png" MyBackgroundColor="Green">
    <ata:ToggleTaskButton.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ata:ToggleTaskButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ata:ToggleTaskButton}">
                        <Viewbox>
                        <Grid>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#FF58595B" BorderThickness="15,15,15,15" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8" >
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFB2B2B2" Offset=".75"/>
                                            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFB2B2B2" />
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <Viewbox>
                                    <Image Margin="25" Height="100" Width="100" Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}" />
                                </Viewbox>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ata:ToggleTaskButton.Resources>
</ata:ToggleTaskButton>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace AdvancedTaskAssigner.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for BluetoothControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class BluetoothControl : ToggleTaskButton
    {
        public BluetoothControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            task = new BrightnessTask();
        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBluetoothState();
            System.Console.Beep(1000, 100);
        }

        private void CheckBluetoothState()
        {
            //bluetoothState = ((byte)task.GetState() == 0x01);
            //Color c = bluetoothState ? (Color)FindResource("enabledColor") : (Color)FindResource("disabledColor");
            //this.outsideColor.Color = c;
        }

        private BrightnessTask task;
        private bool bluetoothState = false;

        private void ToggleTaskButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bluetoothState) { task.PerformTaskDown(); MessageBox.Show("BOO"); System.Console.Beep(1000, 100); } //if bluetooth enabled..disable
            else { task.PerformTaskUp(); System.Console.Beep(2000, 100); MessageBox.Show("BOO"); }//if bluetooth disabled..enable.

            CheckBluetoothState();
        }
    }
}
```

So I end up not really know what I am doing. I want this to be WPF because of the wide array of tablets and various screen sizes I'm giong to deal with. I'm thinking that OnLoad the control should use the bluetooth task to set the State. When the state gets set it changes the color of my second gradient stop on the Border Background. Please help. How do I set the GradientStop's color? And when I add this control to a UserControl in a WPF application it shows nothing, but in my designer it shows one of these 3 buttons

[image]

Comment: In prinitsipe may make it easier, for example using a `Dependency Property`, or the `Visual State Manager`. You want an alternative solution to your problem? Or do you want to do as you wrote?

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev I'm hoping for a solution to my problem. I still have not figured out how to go about making this work properly, but i think i am getting a little closer.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev I guess a better way of saying it is that because I am so new at WPF I don't care if it is a fix to my problem or an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example with a attached dependency property `CurrentStatus`, which contains the current status of the connection. I also created a template for the `Button` triggers that set the properties for the `Button`, depending on the state. At the `Button` can have three states, and add a new state is not difficult.

Example of Button style:

```
<Style x:Key="BlueToothButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gainsboro" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border CornerRadius="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Path x:Name="Bicon" Width="15" Height="27" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 51,47L 36,61L 36,43L 28.25,50L 25.25,46.75L 35,38L 25.25,29.25L 28.25,26L 36,32L 36,14L 51,29L 42,38L 51,47 Z M 41,43L 41,50.5L 44.5,46.5L 41,43 Z M 41,33L 44.5,29.5L 41,25.3995L 41,33 Z "/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(local:DepClass.CurrentStatus)}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(local:DepClass.CurrentStatus)}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E59400" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Bicon" Property="Fill" Value="White" />                                
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here `DataTrigger` sets the value for the status:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(local:DepClass.CurrentStatus)}" Value="1">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
</DataTrigger>
```

The trigger can also look like this:

```
<Trigger Property="local:DepClass.CurrentStatus" Value="1">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E59400" />                            
</Trigger>
```

This will be the same.

`Output`

Status `0`:

[image]

Status `1`:

[image]

Status `2`:

[image]

Listing of `DependencyProperty`:

```
public class DepClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentStatusProperty;

    public static void SetCurrentStatus(DependencyObject DepObject, int value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(CurrentStatusProperty, value);
    }

    public static int GetCurrentStatus(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (int)DepObject.GetValue(CurrentStatusProperty);
    }

    static DepClass()
    {
        PropertyMetadata MyPropertyMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(0);

        CurrentStatusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CurrentStatus",
                                                            typeof(int),
                                                            typeof(DepClass),
                                                            MyPropertyMetadata);
    }        
}
```

Status is defined this way:

```
DepClass.SetCurrentStatus(BluetoothButton, 1);
```

Or in the XAML like this:

```
<Button local:DepClass.CurrentStatus="0" ... />
```

Complete example:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="BluetoothButtonHelp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BluetoothButtonHelp"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BlueToothButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gainsboro" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                            <Path x:Name="Bicon" Width="15" Height="27" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 51,47L 36,61L 36,43L 28.25,50L 25.25,46.75L 35,38L 25.25,29.25L 28.25,26L 36,32L 36,14L 51,29L 42,38L 51,47 Z M 41,43L 41,50.5L 44.5,46.5L 41,43 Z M 41,33L 44.5,29.5L 41,25.3995L 41,33 Z "/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(local:DepClass.CurrentStatus)}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                        </DataTrigger>

                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(local:DepClass.CurrentStatus)}" Value="2">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </DataTrigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E59400" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Bicon" Property="Fill" Value="White" />                                
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Name="BluetoothButton" Style="{StaticResource BlueToothButtonStyle}" local:DepClass.CurrentStatus="0" Width="40" Height="40" />

    <Button Name="Status1" Content="Status 1" Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Status1_Click" />
    <Button Name="Status2" Content="Status 2" Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Status2_Click" />
    <Button Name="Status0" Content="Status 0" Width="100" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Status0_Click" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Status1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DepClass.SetCurrentStatus(BluetoothButton, 1);
    }

    private void Status2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DepClass.SetCurrentStatus(BluetoothButton, 2);
    }

    private void Status0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DepClass.SetCurrentStatus(BluetoothButton, 0);
    }
}

public class DepClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentStatusProperty;

    public static void SetCurrentStatus(DependencyObject DepObject, int value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(CurrentStatusProperty, value);
    }

    public static int GetCurrentStatus(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (int)DepObject.GetValue(CurrentStatusProperty);
    }

    static DepClass()
    {
        PropertyMetadata MyPropertyMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(0);

        CurrentStatusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CurrentStatus",
                                                            typeof(int),
                                                            typeof(DepClass),
                                                            MyPropertyMetadata);
    }        
}
```

Comment: WOW! I am so amazed at this. I hope you didn't have to spend a crazy long time on it. Once I get this implemented and it works I will most likely accept your answer since it looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Robert Snyder: You have no problem with an example? It may be something to explain?

Comment: I didn't get a chance to work on it yesterday. I had to work on a C++ project of mine, so this had to be put on the back burner. I can't wait to try it out though.

Comment: I have tried this all day and have yet to get this to work. It's probably the way that I have this all setup because I don't have just 1 project. I have 3 to narrow it down a little bit. I'm going to pull the important parts out into 2 projects in a different solution and figure this out.. it is really bothering me that i can't get this to work properly..